# interpolating a string to part of a ruby method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have items that can be one of several attributes like red, yellow, green (more complex than this) and they have corresponding is_red, is_yellow, is_green booleans.

I'd like to have an api function to change this value where I pass for example:

```
id: 12
type: red
```

in my function have:

```
item=Item.find(id)
if item.is_ + type == true
  item.is_ + type=false
end
```

How would I do this?

thx in advance

Comment: Don't. Have a single attribute called `Color` and a method `is_color(color)` instead.

Comment: thx, as mentioned in question, it is more complex than just colors (in fact doesn't involve colors).

Comment: I can't think of a single use case where this would be a good idea, even not involving colors.

Comment: legacy system with well constructed graphs of data. works really well

Comment: The question states "variable names" bit the example code references method calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send)

```
item = Item.find(id)

if item.send(:"is_#{type}") == true
  item.send(:"is_#{type}=", false)
end
```

Comment: Send will take either a string or a symbol, so the colons could be omitted if desired.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot build variable names dynamically in Ruby without using `eval`, which would be dirty, but functional.

You could use `method_missing` on a BlankSlate object to capture free text method calls and handle them as a big dirty case statement.

The most elegant solution would be a Hash, because keys can be easily composed dynamically.